# How do I play the co-operative campaign in "The Cave" on the Ouya?

Tags: the-cave, ouya

I purchased Double Fine Productions' "The Cave" on the Ouya. I heard it was an awesome game, and that you could play co-op on it. Any idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be multiplayer on the Ouya version of The Cave:

> Thanks so much for porting this to OUYA. Have had a lot of fun playing it over the last few days. I also think it would be great to be able to transfer this to an external drive as it is so big! **Another thing I would like to see in a future update would be multilayer capability like there is on the XBOX version**. [source](http://www.doublefine.com/forums/viewthread/10287/#309264)